# Mode of an horizontal text array in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, excel-2016, mode

I have a table where I would like to know the most common value of every row, all the data is text.
expected result is column D in picture

Example in picture.

I have tried this formula but it doesnt work, i only get #Value error

```
=INDEX(P2:R2,TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(IF(ISTEXT(P2:R2),MATCH(P2:R2,P2:R2,0)))))
```

[image: Example table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2)),COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`MODE` works on numeric data, so you can, for your example, use:

```
=CHAR(MODE(CODE(A2:C2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but still gives #Value error with this method

Comment: @gatoperez  How do you think the screenshot was generated? The formula was entered in D2 and filled down.  Either your data was different, or your Excel version requires entering the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: This was example data, the info is all the Organizations names (HR, IT, Legal etc.) so Char didnt work as expected. but thanks again for your time